# How to get the public DNS of an instance from another instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Suppose I have launched 5 EC2 instances. What is the easiest way to get the DNS and ip's of all the instances from a particular instance's terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear; you should expand it. However, a few basic tips:

AWS EC2 instances can be assigned public IPs (IPv4 only, currently), which would be displayed in the EC2 control panel. If you're looking to list the IPs directly from the instances, you can do an `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet'` which will show you the *internal* AWS IPs on your VPC.

As far as "DNS", you're going to need to clarify what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tools to do this:

$ aws ec2 describe-instances

...

```
"PublicDnsName": null, 
"EbsOptimized": false, 
"LaunchTime": "2015-04-23T19:43:06.000Z", 
"PublicIpAddress": "54.200.248.x", 
"PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.64", 
"ProductCodes": [],
```

...